# Need to Completely Hide An Image in a CSS Div

Tags: css

Doing a timeline effect with simple mix of HTML, CSS and JS. 
http://iamced.net/2014-1/timeline/index2.html

When hiding an image within a parent div, for some reason the image does entirely hide (as a part of a transition).  How do I add, it seems, another 20% height so that image is totally hidden?

Comment: Post your relevant code *here*, don't just link to your own site. Otherwise, as soon as your 'problem' is solved and you fix your site this question immediately becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

Put something in your body something like:

```
<div id="pic_1></div>
```

Then add jscript to the head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the content of the empty tag with (example):

```
$("#pic_1").hide();
```

Don't forget the number-sign...
backround-image changes didn't work for me and interfere with other backround-images despite other opinions in the web.

Comment: Buddylove: thank you for responding.  I'll try my best to follow your suggestions right now and report back here immediately.

Comment: cant give a ready to roll proposition here (time). just read some articles about jquery and how to manipulate tags and you'll do good. greets

Comment: Buddylove: I'm unclear as to a) what to do with the existing image tag and b) where the URL of the image gets defined if I do away with the image tag.  Here's what I've done:

<div id="pic_1><img src='http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif' width='100%'>$("#pic_1").hide();</div>

Answer (score 0):

Body of your document:

```
<div id="pics"></div> /* unimportant where - you are seperating code */
                      /* from content in css too... */
```

CSS:

```
#pics{
background:url(../rel/path/to/the/pic_1.jpg); /* path goes far from your html */
                                              /* if 'one floor down' it's ../ */
width:100px;
height:100px; /* width&height are mandatory and need to match exact */
}             /* scale your images accordingly */
              /* positioning is still needed with top, left or whatever */
```

script:

```
function change_pic{
var tag=$("#pics")
tag.css("background", "url('../path/to/your/next/pic_2.jpg')");
}
```

If you want to just hide it you don't don't need an explicit function:

```
$("#pics").hide();
```

done.

Of course you can do that with several images.
But the whole crap is already discussed often here.
You seem to be a lazy 'drag and dropper' like I am.

Comment: I've tried what you so kindly instructed. (I'm on 3 hours of sleep only, so I'm getting weary.)

What I'm a bit unclear about how the pic references you made gets applied to over 25 images.  Does each one get properly tagged? Is what I've done at http://iamced.net/2014-1/pint/images acceptable?

http://iamced.net/2014-1/pint/